# SQL Server : cannot get columns to output to varchar

Tags: sql-server, casting

I'm having an odd issue. I have `uid` and `ui2` columns that I combine into a `key` column. Most of the time the uids are an alphanumeric combination and I don't have any issues.

However this set of data the uids are all numeric:

Input data:

```
+-------+-------+
| uid   | uid2  |
+-------+-------+
| 12345 | 98765 |
| 45645 | NULL  |
+-------+-------+
```

What the output SHOULD look like:

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| uid   | uid2  | key        |
+-------+-------+------------+
| 12345 | 98765 | 1234598765 |
| 45645 | NULL  | 45645      |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

If the `uid` is not NULL then it's fine, however, if it is NULL, then it adds a 0 to the end of the uid.  So where `uid=45645` I end up with `456540`

When I combined the two columns, I used `CAST AS varchar(255)`.

I also tried to then `CAST` the entire result.  Neither worked.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    [uid] AS [id], 
    [uid2] AS [id2], 
    (CAST([uid] AS varchar(255)) + CAST(IIF([uid2] IS NULL, ' ', [uid2]) AS varchar(255))) AS [key], 
    (CAST(CAST([uid] AS varchar(255)) + CAST(IIF([uid2] IS NULL, ' ', [uid2]) AS varchar(255)) AS varchar(255))) AS [key]
FROM 
    [test]
```

And that is the output:

```
+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| uid   | uid2  | key        | key        |
+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| 12345 | 98765 | 1234598765 | 1234598765 |
| 45645 | NULL  | 456450     | 456450     |
+-------+-------+------------+------------+
```

The `IIF` is to deal with the NULL. Otherwise it NULLs the entire thing. If I replace the ' ' with '-' then I get

> Error converting data type varchar to float

which makes me think that even though everything is cast to varchar it's still numeric.

As a work around I could probably remove the last 0 from keys were uid2 is NULL, but that's kind of 'hacky' and I'd really like to know what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that SQL Server is trying to convert to int because you have +. I think you just want to use CONCAT like following:

```
select CONCAT(uid, uid2) as key
```

Comment: Winner!  That was simple.  I knew I was at a point where I just couldn't think clearly to come up with the right solution.  Thank you!